# Intuition about residues of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Does the concept of residue go beyond the identification with the coefficient of the term $z^{-1}$ of the Laurent series of a holomorphic function?  Wouldn't the  name for this algebraic entity give a clue?  Is there any geometric/physical idea to understand this number?
I imagine a residue as a obstruction of the domain for the apply the cauchy-goursat theorem; for example, for every closed curve, the integral of holomorphic function is zero; it means for me which is possible to deform the loop in a point and thus the output of integral is zero.

Comment: $Res(f(z),a) = \frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a|=\epsilon} f(s)ds$. We care of the RHS which often appears when simplifying contour integrals (with the Cauchy integral theorem)

Comment: Is this document of interest for you: https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~allenam/IntuitiveResidues.pdf ? Besides, see my recent answer to a classical issue where computing (using residues) a complex integral with a "tuned" contour has allowed to access to the $400$th coefficient of a series expansion ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329652/how-many-different-ways-are-there-to-make-n-dollars-with-1-5-10-25-and-50-ce/4330434#4330434